# ¿Donde se deben validar los datos, en el modelo o en el controlador?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, poo, validación

Inicialmente sabemos que las validaciones desde javascript deben ser obligatorias, mi duda está en el controlador o modelo.

Normalmente realizo las validaciones de laravel validation en el controlador, teniendo en cuenta que esas validaciones realizan la asignación de null en caso que el dato no sea enviado por el usuario, limites, regex, etc, con esto se supone que cuando llegue al modelo los datos están validados.

Si se está utilizando una API, el controlador de la API debe realizar las mismas validaciones. Esto permite que haya duplicidad de código. Si todo se valida en el modelo, entonces antes de que el proceso llege hasta las validaciones del modelo, debe pasar por todo el proceso del controlador, algo que no me parece muy bien ya que hay mayor consumo de recursos y ejecución.

¿Cual considera que es el camino correcto?, validar en el controlador o modelo, o ambos?, teniendo en cuenta el performance y las buenas practicas de codificación.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Donde se deben realizar las validaciones, en el controlador o en el modelo?

Answer (score 1):

Como entendí, creo que el apartado [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) de la documentación puede ayudarte.

Mediante `php artisan make:request UnStoreRequest` generas una clase para que ahí realices todas tus validaciones.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UnStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Lo anterior lo puedes REUTILIZAR en las funciones que quieras, por ejemplo en tu API.

```
use App\Http\Requests\UnStoreRequest;

public function store(UnStoreRequest $request)
{
    //
}
```

Entonces, si vas a validar algo, primero pasa por esa clase, tus validaciones se escribirían en esa clase.

Comment: Perfecto, solo añadiría por como esta enfocada la pregunta que si es una validación pequeña se podráa hacer en el controlador, nunca debería hacerse en el modelo. Te dejo mis puntos. Un saludo.

Comment: Quizas no me di a entender muy bien con la pregunta, pero estaba enfocada a un escenario general (MVC indiferente la tecnología). En laravel se puede utilizar un request personalizando las validaciones, lo cual se valida en el controlador, hasta ahí estamos claros (validaciones en el controlador, ya sea con request o validation). La pregunta me surgió ya que en la empresa me pelearon diciendomen que las validaciones se deben hacer en el modelo, lo cual me puso muy confunso. Gracias por las respuestas.